# Can I SSH to my Google Cloud compute engine VM without allowing traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 in firewall rule?

Tags: ssh, firewall, google-cloud-platform

I wish to access my debian VMs in Google Cloud Compute Engine with SSH, but I don't want to allow traffic from universal range i.e 0.0.0.0/0 in the firewall rules as we process confidential information and want only authorized traffic to connect to our VMs.
Is there a way to attain that?

Comment: The obvious solution is changing the firewall rules to only allow traffic from your IP address(es). What stops you from doing that? I don't really see a question to be answered here.

Comment: We have tried doing that, but then when we try to SSH, 'SSH unable to connect port 22' error comes. It gets corrected when we set the IP ranges to 0.0.0.0/0 again.

Comment: That means you have specified wrong IP addresses in firewall rules. Make sure you have a static IP address where you are connecting with SSH from, and then specify that in firewall rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to try adding one by one the IP to your firewall rule, and see if its not working for all of them or only for a few of them or for a specific one. Another thing you can check is the mask on the firewall rule, probably you are missing something in there. Let me know if you have some progress